# Regex to parse out html from CDATA with C#

Tags: c#, regex, cdata

I would like to parse out any HTML data that is returned wrapped in CDATA.

As an example `<![CDATA[<table><tr><td>Approved</td></tr></table>]]>`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? You've got an XML document, containing a CDATA section, and you want to get a string containing the contents of that CDATA section?

Comment: I am getting this returned in a DataTable as one of the columns in the result set as a string exactly as per the example I wrote above, so I just want to do a regex to get the contents and return to browser just the html string via an AJAX call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression to handle your example would be

```
\<\!\[CDATA\[(?<text>[^\]]*)\]\]\>
```

Where the group "text" will contain your HTML.

The C# code you need is:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
RegexOptions   options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex          regex = new Regex(@"\<\!\[CDATA\[(?<text>[^\]]*)\]\]\>", options);
string         input = @"<![CDATA[<table><tr><td>Approved</td></tr></table>]]>";

// Check for match
bool   isMatch = regex.IsMatch(input);
if( isMatch )
  Match   match = regex.Match(input);
  string   HTMLtext = match.Groups["text"].Value;
end if
```

The "input" variable is in there just to use the sample input you provided

Comment: it's probably more suitable to use .* instead of [^\]]* for the text group otherwise any HTML with the "]" in it will prevent the match.

Answer (score 4):

I know this might seem incredibly simple, but have you tried string.Replace()?

```
string x = "<![CDATA[<table><tr><td>Approved</td></tr></table>]]>";
string y = x.Replace("<![CDATA[", string.Empty).Replace("]]>", string.Empty);
```

There are probably more efficient ways to handle this, but it might be that you want something that easy...

Answer (score 2):

Not much detail, but a very simple regex should match it if there isn't complexity that you didn't describe:

```
/<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>/
```

Comment: Though I don't think escaping "<" is really necessary.

Comment: Escaping < and > is not necessary in c# regex

Answer (score 1):

The regex to find CDATA sections would be:

```
(?:<!\[CDATA\[)(.*?)(?:\]\]>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex("(?<=<!\[CDATA\[).*?(?=\]\])");
```

Comment: Fixed! Sorry, didn't know that was valid in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use Regex for such a simple task?
Try this one:

```
str = str.Trim().Substring(9);
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length-3);
```