# What is the regex expression for CDATA

Tags: xml, regex, parsing, cdata, lex

Hi I have an example CDATA here

```
<![CDATA[asd[f]]]>
```

and

```
<tag1><![CDATA[asd[f]]]></tag1><tag2><![CDATA[asd[f]]]></tag2>
```

The CDATA regex i have is not able to recognize this

```
"<![CDATA["([^\]]|"]"[^\]]|"]]"[^>])*"]]>"
```

this does not work too

```
"<![CDATA["[^\]]*[\]]{2,}([^\]>][^\]]*[\]]{2,})*">"
```

Will someone please give me a regex for `<![CDATA[asd[f]]]>`, I need to use it in Lex/Flex

: I have answered this question, please vote on my answer, thanks.

Comment: Its hard to tell if you escaped the right breckets. Also the xml spec says the first ]]> after <!CDATA[ will terminate the element. So all thats needed is a non-greedy regex `/<!\\[CDATA\[.*?\\]\\]>/s`

Comment: You don't want to use `"` anywhere in that RE.

Comment: And… why not just use an XML parser and work with either a DOM tree or a SAX-like event stream?

Comment: Would love to, except that the documents i got are not strictly XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution. The reason we need to use a START STATE is so that what ever is between `<!CDATA[` and `]]>` does not get match against other REGEX.

```
%option noyywrap
%x CDATA

%%
"<![CDATA[" { BEGIN CDATA; printf("Entering CDATA\n"); }
<CDATA>([^\]]|\n)*|.    { printf("In CDATA: %s\n", yytext); }
<CDATA>"]]>" { 
    printf("End of CDATA\n");
    BEGIN INITIAL;
}

%%
main()
{
    yylex();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Easy enough, it should be this:

```
<!\[CDATA\[.*?\]\]>
```

At least [it works on regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?regex=%3C%21%5c%5bCDATA.%2a%3F%5c%5d%5c%5d%3E&input=%3C%21%5bCDATA%5basd%5bf%5d%5d%5d%3E)

Comment: The main problem is, if I have something like this <abc><![CDATA[asdf]]></abc><abc><![CDATA[asdf]]></abc>. The above REGEX does not recognize the 2 CDATA

Comment: @Freddy no, of course not, that would be awful. If you want to find multiple instances of one thing you need to repeat your search. As you can see here: http://tinyurl.com/2bztpjn it will find multiple instances, but not all at once

Comment: Won't work with flex; it's manual (http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html) doesn't list non-greedy matching (or lookahead assertions, an alternative) as permitted syntax. You'll need start conditions to do a good job.

Comment: @Donal what? I thought ActionScript started as a JavaScript dialect. Have they made it less powerful?

Comment: @Sean: It's not “Flex the Adobe product” but rather “Flex the clone of Lex, the lexical analyzer”. It supports a rather restricted form of regular expressions, so you have to use its higher level language to do it.

Comment: @Donal ahhh, that explains everything :-)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I used your pattern for something I was working on and I ran into an issue where I was getting an error because of the `?`. See my SO question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482388/the-value-cdata-of-the-facet-pattern-is-not-a-valid-re I'm curious why the `?` is there? I was able to get the same result without it, just trying to understand if there's something I am overlooking by removing it.

Comment: @sanpaco The ? is the non-greedy operator. The difference will be obvious if you have multiple sections. Without the ?, it will select everything from the beginning of the first til the end of the last such section

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this is rather awkward to match with the sort of regular expressions used in `lex`; if you had a system that supported EREs, then you'd be able to do either:

```
<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>
```

or

```
<!\[CDATA\[((?:[^]]|\](?!\]>))*)\]\]>
```

(The first uses non-greedy quantifiers, the second uses negative lookahead constraints. OK, it uses non-capturing parens too, but you can use capturing ones there instead; that's not so important.)

It's probably easier to handle this by using a similar strategy to the way C-style comments are handled in `lex`, by having one rule to match the start of the CDATA (on `<![CDATA[`) and put the lexer into a separate state that it leaves on seeing `]]>`, while collecting all the characters in-between. [This](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/ex2_str_comm.html) is instructive on the topic (and it seems that this is an area where `flex` and `lex` differ) and it covers all the strategies that you can take to make this work.

Note that cause of all these problems are because it's very difficult to write a rule with simple regular expressions that expresses the fact that a greedy regular expression must only match a `]` if it is not followed by `]>`. It's much easier to do if you've only got a two-character (or single character!) end-of-interesting-section sequence because you don't need such an elaborate state machine.

Comment: BTW, the two REs above work just fine with sample texts like `<![CDATA[asd[f]]]><![CDATA[asd[f]]]>` which is a fine stress-test for checking whether these patterns are really matching exactly what is wanted.

Comment: Yea, I think you understand my problem pretty well. It seems that a single REGEX expression is not sufficient to capture all the possible CDATA. So I am hoping that someone gives me some instruction on how to capture CDATA using flex/lex preferably avoiding the use of yacc or bison.

Comment: @Freddy: Well definitely read the page I linked to. It's about the problem of matching C comments, but it doubly applies here too.

Comment: In flex, your second regex did not capture the contents (or any). At least `<!\[CDATA\[((?:[^]]|\](?!\]>))*)\]\]>` against `<![CDATA[asd[f]]]><![CDATA[asd[f]]]>` didn't work on [this testing site](http://flexregex.com/)

Comment: @Brad: Of course it didn't. Flex doesn't support EREs. If you'd **read** everything else I wrote, you'd know this already…

Comment: @Donal: That was more in response to your first comment, within the context of this question pertaining to a flex/lex solution. Either way I abstain, this question is starting to feel hostile, an I'm moving on. @Freddy: I hope @Donal is able to help you, he seems to have the answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!\[CDATA\[\s*(?:.(?<!\]\]>)\s*)*\]\]>
```

Previuos answer just modified

Answer (score 2):

One note - a search for CDATA should rule out comments as well, CDATA could be embedded.
`/<!(?:\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]|--.*?--|\[[A-Z][A-Z\ ]*\[.*?\]\])>/sg`
This could be done by checking if group 1 is valid upon each match returned in a global search.

Comment: @Freddy Chua - It does what its supposed to do, so I guess it works. Try changing (?: to just (

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812303/regex-to-parse-out-html-from-cdata-with-c/812343#812343) may be of some help, even though they're grabbing HTML contents and is .NET.

There are other answers with various options for grabbing CDATA in that same question.

CHAD's answer:

```
<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>
```

Matching against:

```
<![CDATA[asd[f]]]>
```

retrieves:

```
asd[f]
```

According to [FlexRegEx](http://flexregex.com/) anyways.

Comment: Tried all. Does not compile in Flex

Comment: It does not work if I do this <![CDATA[asd[f]]]><![CDATA[asd[f]]]>. Chad's regex recognizes the CDATA as a single CDATA instead of two. I need it to be two CDATA

Comment: @Freddy: I assume your content contains `]]>` within the string and needs to be escaped? otherwise, this is not consistent with how CDATA is used.

Comment: The main problem is, if I have something like this <abc><![CDATA[asdf]]></abc><abc><![CDATA[asdf]]></abc>. The above REGEX does not recognize the 2 CDATA

Comment: @Freddy: If you're using regex to parse an XML document, you're going to have a lot of problems arising. XML parsers already take care of the CDATA and extract the content from it. If this is something else you're doing (and I don't pretend to be completely familiar with flex) you should be able to use a global match or match back-to-back to get the multiple results that may be present.

Comment: @Brad: It's not safe to assume that nobody's going to pitch an evil multi-CDATA chunk at you. It's uncommon, but assuming that the uncommon never happens gets you into real trouble. (It's the old Microsoft approach to security, and it's taken them *years* to root it out of their code.)

Comment: Someone handed me a bunch of 10 GB documents that follow a very loose form of XML and I am trying to parse them. The typical XML parser from java or python does not work on it, so I am trying to write my own, I am almost getting there, just need to clear this CDATA hurdle. Thanks for help guys.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Never said not to take a safe approach, I merely said it's not typical. I can only judge based on the information that is in front of me. With that being said and now that I know the source, regex is never a good solution to the xml/html structure (need to bring up the obligatory post?). For that reason alone, nothing I could provide in a regex would make a good bid against being practical or safe, so what's the use in even making a bid via this route? Don't get me wrong,  over-code things commonly but I just see this from a 'get it done' approach.

Comment: I get it now, probably a 1 line REGEX will not solve the problem. I will try to use the Start States approach in FLEX, will post solution if I have it. Btw, anyone familiar with Flex/Lex start states ? Should try to gimme a solution if you have one. :)