# I need a regex that matches CDATA elements in html

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, cdata

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match CDATA elements in HTML in a web crawler class in c#.

What I have used in the past is : `\<\!\[CDATA\[(?<text>[^\]]*)\]\]\>` , but the problem is that this breaks in the presence of array [] elements if there is javascript contained within the CDATA tags. The negation is necessary because if there are multiple       I want to match them all.

If I modify the regex to match the end '>' character I have the same problem. Any javascript with a > operator breaks my regex.

So I need to use a negative look-ahead within this regex to ignore ']]>'. How would I write this?

Here's some test data for a quick setup of the problem:

```
        //Matches any
        string pattern = @"\<\!\[CDATA\[(?<text>[^\]]*)\]\]\>";
        var rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        /* Testing...*/

         string eg = @"<![CDATA[TesteyMcTest//]]><![CDATA[TesteyMcTest2//]]><![CDATA[TesteyMcTest//]]><!             [CDATA[TesteyMcTest2//]]>
         <![CDATA[Thisisal3ongarbi4trarys6testwithnumbers//]]><![CDATA             [thisisalo4ngarbitrarytest6withumbers123456//]]><![CDATA[ this.exec = (function(){ var x =              this.GetFakeArray(); var y = x[0]; return y > 3;});//]]> ";

         var mz = rx.Matches(eg);
```

This example matches every instance of CDATA except for the last one, which contains javascript and ']', '>'

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616554/what-is-the-regex-expression-for-cdata

Comment: Add some test cases please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `<text>` subpattern is false! You don't need to avoid `]`, you need to avoid **`]` followed by `]>`**. You can use this subpattern instead:

```
(?<text>(?>[^]]+|](?!]>))*)
```

the whole pattern: *(note that many characters don't need to be escaped)*

```
@"<!\s*\[CDATA\s*\[(?<text>(?>[^]]+|](?!]>))*)]]>"
```

*I added two `\s*` to match all your example strings, but if you want to disallow these optional spaces, you can remove the `\s*`.*

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you: http://regex101.com/r/cT0pT0

```
\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>
```

It *seems* to match what you are asking for... Key here is that the use of `.*?` (non greedy match) stops on the first occasion that you get `]]>`

NOTE - it is usually a REALLY BAD IDEA to use regex for parsing HTML. There are plenty of good libraries available to do the job far more robustly.

See for example [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56107/1967396)

Comment: Right. I'm not using purely regex to parse the html document, I'm using html agility pack to do the heavy lifting, which leaves me with some CDATA elements to clean up.

Comment: @DavidDworetzky good to hear it. Does my expression work for you? If it doesn't (it seems to work on the test cases you gave) can you expand your test cases?